# Modifying the Unity Piratebay Scope to open URI with a torrent streamer instead of the default client

Tags: python, ubuntu, glib

Honestly don't entirely know what I am doing but I am trying to make the Pirate Bay Scope open its results with Acestream Player.  One of the problems being Acestream doesn't know how to handle magnetic links.

The original code, which follows, uses `gvfs-open` to open the with the default application.

```python
def on_activate_uri (self, scope, uri):
    if uri.startswith("more"):
        results = self.scope.props.results_model
        page = uri.split('__')[2]
        search = uri.split('__')[1]
        results.remove(results.get_iter_at_row(results.get_n_rows()-1))
        self.update_results_model (search, results, page)
        return Unity.ActivationResponse(handled=Unity.HandledType.SHOW_DASH, goto_uri="")
    else:
        print uri
        GLib.spawn_command_line_async('gvfs-open %s' % uri)
        return Unity.ActivationResponse(handled=Unity.HandledType.HIDE_DASH, goto_uri='')
```

I have modified one line so it is:

```vala
GLib.spawn_command_line_async("aria2c -d /path/.torrents --on-download-complete /path/.torrent.sh --bt-metadata-only=true --bt-save-metadata=true '%s'" % uri)
```

I am using aria2c to connect to the magnetic link and download a torrent file, and once the file has been downloaded aria2c runs a bash script which opens the torrent file with Acestream.  This process works fine on the command line.  I am guessing my syntax is wrong.

I can tell that selecting the torrent from the scope runs aria2c and it opens ports, but a torrent file is not created and my script is not executed.  Oddly enough when I added `gnome-terminal -x` to the front of my command line, to watch it run for debugging purposes, it succeeds in creating the torrent file and my script opens Acestream for a fleeting second.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked by spelling out each command I wanted to run using Popen the final implementation follows.

```python
    else:
        print uri
        subprocess.Popen('rm /path/.torrents/*', shell=True)
        subprocess.Popen('gnome-terminal -x aria2c --allow-overwrite=true -d /path/.torrents --bt-metadata-only=true --bt-save-metadata=true \'%s\'' % uri, shell=True).wait()
        torrent = subprocess.check_output('ls /path/.torrents/*', shell=True).strip()
        GLib.spawn_command_line_async('acestreamplayer %s' % torrent)
        return Unity.ActivationResponse(handled=Unity.HandledType.HIDE_DASH, goto_uri='')
```

Now I just need to parse out the adult hits.  It is for the family entertainment system after all.